Create CAfile for openssl parameter
I have to give an OpenSSL-command the parameter CAfile with multiple certificates included.
Need it for s_client a TLS-connection.
Lets say my cafile should be mycafile.pem and the certs I need inside are cert1.pem and cert2.pem.
Is it only a concat of the requeired pem-files or some different format?
cat cert1.pem cert2.pem > mycafile.pem

Is there a order of inserting??

If this is about different (and thus unrelated) root CA cert1.pem and cert2.pem then the order in the mycafile.pem does not matter. If this is not about root CA then CAfile is the wrong parameter.
